# Error using stored procedure as source for DbSet.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have this C# code, running with ef 6.1.1:

```
string query = string.Format("exec arch_SP_GeneraEstructuraPlano {0} ,@p_clausulaWhereAdicional = ' where NumIdLote = {1}',@p_GenerarRuta=0", IdEscenario, IdLote);

DbSet mov = db.Set(typeof(vw_InterfazContableMegasistemasMov));
List<vw_InterfazContableMegasistemasMov> Detalle =  new List<vw_InterfazContableMegasistemasMov>(mov.SqlQuery(query)
    .Cast<vw_InterfazContableMegasistemasMov>()
    .AsQueryable());
```

If I execute query in SQL Server, it returns n **unique** records, but with the above code returns the **same** record n times.

I'm using DbSet transformation because the stored procedure could return different structures depending on scenario variable.

**Edit 1:** Searching for another approach, found Translate  of IObjectContextAdapter

This is my code It doesn't work to :(

```
db = new MyDbContext();
db.Database.Connection.Open();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var data1 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
    .ObjectContext
    .Translate<vw_InterfazContableMegasistemasMov>(reader, "vw_InterfazContableMegasistemasMov", MergeOption.AppendOnly)
    .AsQueryable();
```

How can I  force DbSet query to load all records?.

Comment: There may be problem with id, if EF sees that different rows have same logical Id it will just use already loaded row.

Comment: you are totally ok. The problem is with EF Primary key, Just change my primary key at my Entity and now works well.